# Unity as a library for macOS native application

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, swiftui

I am working with Unity as a library for iOS quite a while now. This is described on unitys website: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary.html.

This works fine but I am wondering if there is a way to integrate unity in a native macOS application as well. I know writing native objC plugins is possible for unity but as I need to use Views from SwiftUI this is not sufficient. I also thought about using Flutter as a bridge but unfortunately the library to integrate unity in a flutter application (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) also does not work for macOS.

Is there a way to accomplish native macOS views in a unity application?